# alias for nested template type

Tags: c++, templates

I have the following code:

```
template <template <typename, typename...> typename trait_t, typename arg_t>
struct BindFirst
{
    template <typename... arg_ts>
    using result_t = trait_t<arg_t, arg_ts...>;
};

#define BIND_FIRST(trait_t, arg_t) BindFirst<trait_t, arg_t>::template result_t
```

you can use it to bind the first argument of a trait like this:

```
BIND_FIRST(std::is_same, double)
```

The result is equivalent to:

```
template <typename T>
struct IsInt : std::is_same<double, T> { };
```

The difference is, that you can use it inline. For example like this:

```
using result_t = find_t<type_list, BIND_FIRST(std::is_same, double)>;
```

This works but i like to avoid the define. I tried to use an alias. But I have no idea how to apply it. Is there any way to replace the define?

Comment: how do you intend to use the macro/alias? a small example of its usage would be nice

Comment: I've added an example

Answer (score 1):

You can use templates with `using` to create an alias template, just like you did for `result_t`.

```
template <typename... Args>
using IsDouble = BindFirst<std::is_same, double>::template result_t<Args...>;
```

You can limit the `Args...` to a single type `T` as well, it doesn't have to be variadic.

**Edit:** If your goal is to reduce boilerplate, you may want to opt for something like this

```
template <typename T, typename U>
using IsSameAs = std::is_same<T, U>;

template <typename T>
using IsDouble = IsSameAs<double, T>;
```

Comment: Nitpicking on terminology somewhat, but a *using directive* is the form `using namespace X;`. A *using declaration* is something like `using std::swap;`. What you're referring to is called an *alias template*.

Comment: You'll also need a `template` specifier right before `result_t`, because it's a dependent template name. Your second example won't compile, you can't use alias templates in such a way. You'll need to wrap it in a struct, but then @Martin Kalbfuß is right back where he started.

Comment: hmm, [ideone](https://ideone.com/bAx5RS) lets me. I'll check more compilers to see if I'm spreading lies.

Comment: @oisyn I think you're right, it'd be cool to do that though. edited

Comment: Yeah I see, GCC is apparently accepting it. It makes no sense, because you're not even referencing the template parameter in your `IsDouble` alias template, so it shouldn't even do anything with it (see `std::void_t` for a good example of unused template parameters in an alias template).  Experimentation showed `IsDouble<int>` becomes `std::is_same<int, double>`. Freaky stuff :)